# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError loading Images in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

*This question refers to Codename One only.*

I have a `Form` with a `Tabs` and each tab can contain an arbitrary number of images (taken from the Gallery).

Result: after few images (eight images from the gallery), on my Android device I get:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5683356 byte allocation with 1845080 free bytes and 1801KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:737)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:703)
        at com.codename1.impl.android.c.b(AndroidImplementation.java:2037)
        at com.codename1.r.z.a(Image.java:531)
        at cool.teammate.apps.frontend.b.e.a$1.a(BasePageForm.java:208)
        at com.codename1.r.l.b.a(EventDispatcher.java:349)
        at com.codename1.impl.android.c.a(AndroidImplementation.java:7336)
        at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity$6.run(CodenameOneActivity.java:527)
        at com.codename1.r.r.n(Display.java:1298)
        at com.codename1.r.r.l(Display.java:1242)
        at com.codename1.r.r.k(Display.java:1130)
        at com.codename1.r.aq.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
        at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

Also iOS crashes, but I haven't the log.

Each image is scaled before showing (using the class `FixedSizeButton`, that I reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983658/saving-and-loading-images-from-the-storage-in-codename-one)). Any suggestion?

I guess that the [`dispose()`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#dispose--) method of `Image` can be useful, but it's written to "DO NOT CALL THIS METHOD UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING". Is it so problematic? For example, can it help if I `dispose` an Image after saving it to file and/or after scaling?

I also guess that `System.gc()` can be useful.

However, if few photos are so problematic... how can I make a photo gallery inside a `Form` without this kind of issues? Same problem to load hundreds of photo post inside an `InfiniteContainer`...

Note that the memory issue happens regardless if I insert the images as `icon` of a `Button` or as filled background of the `Button`.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `dispose()` or `gc()` for a proper application. You're trying to load a 5mb image which I'm assuming is a 5mb JPEG. That's probably from a 9+ mega pixel camera which means the decompressed size would be roughly 9 x 4 == 36MB!

So 36 x 8 = 288mb of RAM.

```
    this.image = Image.createImage(this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight, 0xFFdddddd);
```

What's imageWidth/Height?

You might be taking a lot of RAM here...

```
    this.setIcon(this.image);

    EasyThread scalingThread = EasyThread.start("FixedSizeButton-ScalingImg-" + fileName);
```

Since you're creating multiple threads you might have all 8 images in RAM at once.

A better way is to use one image scaling thread. An even better approach is avoiding `scaled` altogether and using `ImageIO` to scale the image without loading it into RAM.